# How to hide the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zfxrxzLg/ Look at this for full code

Why does the last picture collapses underneath, and isn't hidden as it should be? I'm trying to create a slider. I'm thinking that might be the issue why the slider isn't working.

### HTML

```
<div class="gallery-wrap">
  <div class="gallery clearfix">


     <div class="gallery__item">
          <img src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8439353-md.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
     </div>
     <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8439353-md.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
     </div>

     <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8439353-md.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
     </div>

    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8439353-md.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>

    <div class="gallery__item">
      <img src="http://gallery.photo.net/photo/8439353-md.jpg" class="gallery__img" alt="" />
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
.gallery-wrap { 

    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 432px;
}
.gallery { 
    position: relative;
    left: 0; 
    top: 0; 
}
.gallery__item { 
    float: left; 
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.gallery__img { 
    display: block;
    border: 4px solid #40331b;
    height: 80px; 
    width: 80px; }

.gallery__controls { margin-top: 10px; }
.gallery__controls-prev { cursor: pointer; float: left; }
.gallery__controls-next { cursor: pointer; float: right; }

.clearfix:after{
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display:block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(".gallery__link").fancybox({
        'titleShow'     : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic'
    });
    var totalWidth = 0;

    $(".gallery__item").each(function(){
        totalWidth = totalWidth + $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    var maxScrollPosition = totalWidth - $(".gallery-wrap").outerWidth();

    function toGalleryItem($targetItem){
        if($targetItem.length){
            var newPosition = $targetItem.position().left;
            if(newPosition <= maxScrollPosition){


                $targetItem.addClass("gallery__item--active");


                $targetItem.siblings().removeClass("gallery__item--active");
              $(".gallery").animate({
                    left : - newPosition
                });
            } else {

                $(".gallery").animate({
                    left : - maxScrollPosition
                });
            };
        };
    };

       $(".gallery").width(totalWidth);
    $(".gallery__item:first").addClass("gallery__item--active");


    $(".gallery__controls-prev").click(function(){
        var $targetItem = $(".gallery__item--active").prev();
        toGalleryItem($targetItem);
    });


    $(".gallery__controls-next").click(function(){
        var $targetItem = $(".gallery__item--active").next();
        toGalleryItem($targetItem);
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to work fine if I remove your fancybox (as the script isn't included) and add jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/zfxrxzLg/1/.  Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: if you are looking why it is not working at Fiddle? than the answer is FancyBox Plugin

Comment: @Pete yeah, it works, but why did the Fancybox messed it up? and about the whitespace, do you mean that I should just minify the HTML code by that??

Comment: @TacoCat just put the fancybox in the end of the `.load` method and make some fixes to your javascript, modularize better your code. an example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPzywy)

Comment: The fancybox was messing up your fiddle as you hadn't included the fancybox js so it didn't know what it was - I removed it as it wasn't essential to see if the rest of your code was working (which it is).  There must be an error in your local version (press f12 in chrome and click on the console tab).  The white space comment below is for if you use inline-block elements instead of block elements floated, if you did that you would either have to recalculate the width you scroll or comment out the white space between elements, if you stick with your code and styling then you don't need to

Answer (score 2):

few corrections and additions:

```
.gallery__item {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.gallery {
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I love you. You use inline-block!! If you were another person possible you use float:left but you are better than this! Thank you for show us this code.

Comment: don't forget if you do it like this then you need to comment out the white space between the `.gallery__item` elements, otherwise you will get extra margin between the elements that the slider will have to account for

Comment: hi @Era by adding your correction i can't find prev and next control working can you please look at that.? are your working..?